# Recursive slug url in mysql

Tags: mysql, recursion

I looking for mysql query / function to build slug url recursive in self-join mysql table

[image]

I need `slug` in `term` with `id = 4` is `category-2/category-2-1`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the more heavy weight database systems, MySQL does not support anything fancy like a recursive CTE/query.  But we can simulate a recursive query by just doing a certain number of self joins:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t3.slug IS NOT NULL
         THEN CONCAT(t3.slug, '/', t2.slug, '/', t1.slug)
         WHEN t2.slug IS NOT NULL
         THEN CONCAT(t2.slug, '/', t1.slug)
         ELSE t1.slug END AS slug
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.term_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t2.term_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = 4;
```

**Output:**

```
    slug
1   category-2/category-2-1
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

In the demo you can remove the `WHERE` condition to see that the correct paths are being formed for every entry in the table.  It would also be easy to extend this query to go deeper in the hierarchy if necessary.

Comment: So, category-2/category-2-1/category-2-1-1/category-2-1-1-1 is hard to query (need t4 t5 etc) ?

Comment: That depends on what your meaning of the word "hard" is.  If this solution doesn't work for you then just search SO for "hierarchical query MySQL."  There are other options.